# How to take data from MYSQL to windows forms app and fill strings in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I'm new to this long story short I have table in my database called `data`, it has 3 columns ID, type, info after filling data with 10 rows

I need to run windows forms and have a button that acquire  the information from these rows and store them in 10 strings .

```
string1 = ( get string type from row 1 )

string 2 = ( get string type from row 2)
until string 10
```

I can use this code to get the specific row one

```
string query = "select * from data where id=1";

MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(info);
MySqlCommand dbcommand = new MySqlCommand(query, connect);

MySqlDataReader myreader;

try
{
    connect.Open();
    myreader = dbcommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (myreader.Read())
    {
        string1 = (string)myreader["type"];
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}

connect.Close();
```

What's the best way to make the code to get 10 rows ins stores info in the 10 strings .

Thank you

Comment: Look into this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataAdapter.htm -- it will make your interactions between app and mysql much easier.  The example at the bottom of the page is exactly what you need. When possible, you can grab all your required results in 1 query, and then parse them in your app code.  Avoid '*' whenever possible, it will be a good habit to have when you start working in larger systems.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after reading your question a few times I think I understand what you're trying to get at. You want to store 10 strings wich each should contain the data that inside the 'type' column of a row in your database.

Your onto the right track the most simple solution is to create a new List and store the strings in there when looping trough each row.

Example:

```
try
    {
        string query = "select * from data";

        List<string> strings = new List<string>();

        MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(info);
        MySqlCommand dbcommand = new MySqlCommand(query, connect);

        connect.Open();

        myreader = dbcommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (myreader.Read())
        {
            strings.add(Convert.ToString(myreader["type"]));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    connect.Close();
```

After adding all the strings into one collection you could return the collection and loop trough it to retrieve your strings back.

```
foreach (string s in strings)
{
   //do something with "s"
}
```

I would also recommend you lookup a better solution for opening and closing your database connection. its pretty messy right now.

Answer (score 0):

First, store your results in an array instead of 10 separate variables, loop through and load each one until you can't read any more or read the number you wanted.

This is a quick write up using your approach, I put your `MySqlConnection` in a `using` block though:

```
string query = "select * from data where id=1";

using (MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(info))
{
    MySqlCommand dbcommand = new MySqlCommand(query, connect);
    connect.Open();

    int i = 0;
    int numStrings = 10;
    string[] strings = new string[numStrings];

    MySqlDataReader myreader = dbcommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (myreader.Read() && i < numStrings)
    {
        strings[i++] = (string)myreader["type"];
    }
}
```

The results are then accessible through the `strings` array, so the first is in `strings[0]` and the 10th is in `strings[9]`.

Comment: OOPS, I meant to post my comment to the original question, not this answer, sorry.